# Manage.py is not working or even giving any type of error

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I am new in Django and I want to launch my portfolio site on my vps.

The problem is none of my manage.py commands are working and I don't even get an error when I press enter and a new commands line comes...

I restarted my vps and searched on internet but cant find a solution, all commands are working on my local computer but not in my vps.

Please help me.
thanks

Comment: what's in the file **manage.py** that you're trying to launch?

Comment: How do you know that your commands are not working ? Maybe they are but the output is not showing up for some reason.

Comment: **Exactly** what are you typing on your VPS? You shouldn't need to run manage.py to serve your site in production.

Comment: well first #!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'portfolio.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()

Comment: dear louis when i type python manage.py in my local computer it shows a list but not in my vps. and other commands are working in my local as well.

Comment: Dear Daniel i am following a tutorial made by nick walter

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you are typing on the command line (following a tutorial made by ... doesn't tell us anything)

Comment: You still didn't tell us what you are typing.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem!
my application keeps using python 2 instead of python 3
the mistake I made was: trying fixing the syntax errors manually.
when I copy pasted the local version of manage.py to my server problem was solved.
but now I still have the former problem which is my app is using python 2 as default and I can't find how to force it to use python 3....
right now I receive import error which is caused by using python 2 .....